# How to detect whether browser supports chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chromium, browser-feature-detection

I need to test whether a web page is loaded in a browser which supports Chrome extensions installed from the Chrome Web Store.
* Google Chrome and  MS Edge should return a **positive** result.
* Chrome for Android should return a **negative** result.

Testing for the existence of `window.chrome` is not good enough. Chrome for Android, for example, will expose `window.chrome` but it does not support Chrome extensions.
I want to avoid user-agent sniffing and media queries if possible, since those methods are prone for errors.

Is there a javascript API I can use to test for extension support?
Is testing for `window.chrome.runtime` good enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Chrome 105 and older

If your site is `https` you can test for the presence of `window.chrome.runtime.sendMessage` - it's exposed in Chromium on all https pages by the built-in browser extension for CryptoToken authorization support.

P.S. there are chromium forks that can run extensions on Android e.g. Kiwi, Yandex.

#### Chrome 106 and newer

There's no reliable method.

Until [crbug/1370496](https://crbug.com/1370496) is fixed you'll have to infer it from `navigator.userAgent`.
You can also check the web page for presence of artifacts from known extensions e.g. Stylus extension adds DOM elements to document.documentElement that match `style.stylus[id^="stylus-"]`.

Comment: With the release of v106 (September, 2022), Chromium no longer guarantees the existence of `chrome.runtime` on all pages.

Wondering if there is any other way?